# How to Integrate QR code scanner with android application

Tags: android, macos, qr-code

I need to generate and scan QR codes in android application. I need this feature to basically convert some password to QR code and then use the QR code scanner to scan that password from QR code, so that I can validate it. I search and came to know that zxing but I am not getting how to integrate it and use it. I would be greatful if someone could be pointers on how to integrate QR codes scanner with android application.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to integrate zxing to my android project.

- svn, checkout the zxing sources
- Create a Android project on your eclipse, Delete main.xml, from the new project, Right click on “src” directory and hit import. Browse to the following directories in the order mentioned. As you add them for import one by one, ensure that you have the src directory in the edit field of the import wizard. And that you select only the “com” directory on the left directory tree. Do not select src.

  - core
  - android-integration
  - android
- Android sdk version should be atleast 9
- Some Strings.xml will report errors, just put a `/` before the `'` characters to escape it

Check out [this](http://www.4shared.com/file/bFx8Y5Ys/zXingJune2010.html), a sample integrated project

Answer (score 0):

i developed qr code scanner using zxing but it's not worked properly so i am used this link (https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner) it's work good compare to zxing.